# Curious words that make me suspicious

Tags: meaning, grammar, adjectives, ambiguity, homonyms

> I'm *curious* about that *curious* object.
>
> I'm *suspicious* of that *suspicious* stranger.
>
> I'm *dubious* about that *dubious* plan.

I can't think of any other words that allow this: using the same term to describe the observer and the target. You can't say *I'm excited about my excited present*, for instance.

The point about these words is that *I'm curious about that object* means the same thing as *That is a curious object*. That is not the case for something like *furious*: one can say *I'm furious about that man*, and *That man is furious*, but they certainly don't mean the same.

Here's another way of looking at the oddity. If I say

> That stranger is *suspicious*.

then it's ambiguous as to whether the stranger is suspicious as *observer* (i.e., the stranger is suspicious *of* something) or as *target* (i.e., I am suspicious of the stranger). One can construct similar examples for *curious* and *dubious*. This doesn't apply to other words.

1. Is it just fluke that these all end in *-ious*? There are plenty of such words for which it doesn't work (like *furious*).
2. What's going on here? Are these homonyms, so that *curious* is a different word when applied to observer and target? Or is it *hypallage*, transferring the epithet properly applied to the observer onto the target?

Comment: I am sad about that sad thing. I am happy about that happy coincidence. I am stinky about that stinky detail. I am mad at that mad plan. I am fucked up by that fucked up mountain. I am giddy because of this giddy height. And I am limited by the limited space here.

Comment: @RegDwigнt You're stinky? How would this manifest itself?

Comment: @RegDwigнt I've added something to clarify. It will help with some of your examples, I think.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I've clarified further. The *happy coincidence* is interesting, because that is definitely hypallage; this makes me think that's how to characterise the examples I gave.

Comment: That stranger is healthy. Doesn't tell you if he is in good health himself, or good for your health, e.g. if you're a lion talking to another lion.

Comment: I submit that there are dozens of examples, and if we can't think of one, that merely means we're not thinking hard enough.

Comment: "I'm serious about that serious man" and "I'm careful about that careful mother", "I was committed by that committed board" are other candidates.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "I'm serious about that man" doesn't mean the same as "That man is serious". With my examples, the sentences mean the same. "I'm curious about that object" means the same as "That object is curious".

Comment: Not necessarily, the object needn't be curious in order to pique your curiosity. To one observer the object could be unremarkable to another curious. Who has deemed the object to be curious? The speaker or some external authority?

Answer (score 1):

The three examples you give are all adjectives - you are curious, and the object is also curious. But when you say **I am excited** you are not using an adjective, you are using a present participle from the verb **to excite**, and the adjective from this is **exciting**.

You *could* say **I am furious about the furious man** (though it sounds a bit weird), meaning that you were angry that the man was angry.

I'm trying to think of an adjective that doesn't end in -ious which follows the same pattern. Watch this space!

Comment: Thanks! I've edited the question to explain in a little more detail, and in particular to say why I don't think *furious* works as an example.